# Change value into int

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So my question is: I run a SQL Query and my result is:

```
week   sale sale override sell through(%)
Week-1  42  29            3.94804504619449
Week-2  46  36            3.39242402149418
Week-3  53  44            3.91839149445099
Week-4  44  33            3.53663152826439
Week-5  45  20            4.12465416879239
Week-6  45  24            3.9861284151902
Week-7  47  10            3.93148317015786
Week-8  27  14            4.96932263953541
Week-9  49  18            3.6518835739424
Week-10 56  35            3.54296186103223
Week-11 44  23            3.42675072960917
Week-12 42  28            3.73042394308072
```

So I want now change sell through(%) into this:

```
week   sale sale override sell through(%)
Week-1  42  29            39
Week-2  46  36            33
Week-3  53  44            39
Week-4  44  33            35
Week-5  45  20            41
Week-6  45  24            39
Week-7  47  10            39
Week-8  27  14            49
Week-9  49  18            36
Week-10 56  35            35
Week-11 44  23            34
Week-12 42  28            37
```

Is there a way to change value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data you have shown, it looks like you need to wrap the generation of `sell through(%)` in `FLOOR(10.0 *...)` e.g. if your existing query was used as a subquery you could write:

```
SELECT [week], [sale], [sale override],
       FLOOR(10.0 * [sell through(%)]) AS [sell through(%)]
FROM (
  -- your existing query
) d
```

Comment: thank you your query work but change my value little bit is this normal

Comment: @YasirBilal which values are not what you expect?

Comment: as i mention above

Comment: @YasirBilal it seems to give the correct results here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1a0ed/3

Comment: i'm using sum() as well not sure if i'm getting little bit change value because of that??

Comment: @YasirBilal that shouldn't make a difference... perhaps you need `FLOOR(10.0 * (your formula))`?

Comment: select Week,
sum(sale) as sale,
sum([sale Override]) as SaleOverride,
sum(FLOOR(10.0 * [Sell Through])) as SellThrough
from [sale]
group by Week
order by len(Week), Week that my query

Comment: You need to use `FLOOR(10.0 * SUM([Sell Through]))`. If you do the rounding first you will get errors; it has to be the last operation.

Comment: thank you for helping i'm getting right value now thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your query:

```
declare @float float = '3.94804504619449'
select cast(@float * 10 as int)
```